# Terraria and the HOIK glitch

Tags: terraria

The HOIK is a glitch that involves an abuse of slopes, which mess up the positionning of the players/items around the slopes, by making instant movement, which can trigger others instant movements with further slopes.

With this, you can travel horizontally at the speed of **2 blocks per frame**
and vertically at the speed of **3 blocks per frame**.
I believe it is the fastest speed ever reached in Terraria as for the **1.2.4.1** version.

What I need to know about the HOIK is ... why does the game have this behavior with the slopes ?

Comment: Unfortunately, as a glitch, it might be patched in the upcoming 1.3 update, thus ruining a lot of automatic mechanisms such as binary calculator. (I hope the devs don't, this glitch is awesome !!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe only a developer could answer this question concretely.

That said, my educated guess as to why HOIK'ing works like it does is due to the collision detection algorithm used in the game. Collision detection in any sort of game (2D or 3D) is a non-trivial problem. When Terraria introduced sloped blocks, I'm guessing the programmers made a few design decisions on how to handle the collision detection between the player's sprite and the sloped block (which is, by definition, a fraction of a whole block). These design decisions work for the rational cases (e.g. the player running up a sloped hill). The design didn't take into account the strange cases that HOIK'ing takes advantage of (e.g. the player uses sloped blocks pointing the other way to travel through solid blocks).

Since I don't have access to the source code, I can't say for sure. My guess is that this exploit could be fixed, at the expense of a few extra compute cycles dedicated to collision detection during every game tick.

Comment: This settles the question then. I'll look forward for it when the 1.3 version will come out.